# Laravel: Update model's timestamps without saving other attributes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an issue with the `Illuminate\Database\Model::touch()` method.  Here's the flow:

1. I'm temporarily decrypting the field inside the model to send to the authorized user.
2. Updating `updated_at` timestamp with new log entry to indicate that field was decrypted.
3. Returning decrypted model with the response without saving it in DB.

**The issue:**

So, here's the problem: When I do `$model->touch()` it is saving the whole model (as expected as Laravel's only checking if `updated_at` column `isDirty()`, not the whole model, and then calling `$this->save()`).

**Question:**

Is there another method that I can use to just update the model's timestamps in DB regardless of if other attributes have been changed?

Comment: `$modelnstance->update(['updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()]);`

Comment: Should do the trick! Will override `touch()` method in global `Model` class with correct checks to only update `updated_at` column. Thank you!